# How to run an ANOVA with incomplete factorial? (2x2) + 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, fractional-factorial

I am running a study where we are testing the effects of three interventions, A, B, and C. However, B and C interventions require the A intervention. So I have a 2x2 design, testing combinations of B and C, as well as a fifth control group that contains neither A, B, or C.

- Control group: None
- Group 1: A
- Group 2: AB
- Group 3: AC
- Group 4: ABC

The hypotheses I want to test:

1. Effect of A
2. Effect of B
3. Effect of C
4. Interaction effect of B and C

I realize that I can run a 2 way ANOVA for Groups 1-4 and test hypotheses 1-3, but I also want to compare Group 1 with Control to assess the effect of A. I could run an additional t-test plus the 2 way ANOVA, but that increases my chance of Type I error, right? Would Bonferroni be able to solve this?

Alternatively, is there a way to run a 3 way ANOVA with missing cells? I think this would be considered an incomplete factorial, but I haven't found many resources on how to go about this.